# Powershell - build a custom object with an unknown number of columns

Tags: powershell

I need to create a CSV that contains all possible emails addresses that an Active Directory user has. The CSV must be in the following format (very rigid API for where their going to be imported to):

```
Username | EmailAddress1 | EmailAddress2 | EmailAddressN
```

My script so far looks like this:

```
$Group = "GroupNAme
$usersObj = @()
$countMax = 0

$GetAdGroup = Get-AdGroup -Identity $Group -Properties *
[array]$members = $GetAdGroup.Members

ForEach ($member in $members) {
    $currentUser = get-aduser -Identity $member `
        -Properties EmailAddress, ProxyAddresses |
            Where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"}
    $countTemp = ($currentUser.ProxyAddresses).count
    if ($countTemp -gt $countMax){ $countMax = $countTemp}

    foreach ($mailAdd in $currentUser.ProxyAddresses) {    
        $usersOBJ += [pscustomobject]@{
            'Username' = $currentUser.SamAccountName;`
            'ProxyAddresses' = $mailAdd.SubString(5)
        }
    }    

    $usersOBJ | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation C:\Export.csv
```

Now my existing Object spits out the Users as follows:

```
UserName | Emailaddress1
Username | Emailaddress2
Username | EmailsaddressN
```

I can't seem to make the leap into working out how to create a better object. I can get the max number of ProxyAddresses that occur but I'm not sure how to figure that into building my object and then populating the values of the $currentUser.ProxyAddresses into those columns.

I've read about Hash tables but they don't seem to fit my requirements, usually taking the form:

```
Username1     | Username2
Emailaddress1 | Emailaddress1
Emailaddress2 | Emailaddress2
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to separate the values you're adding a bit. Add the username to a single object before the loop, then add additional properties on an as-needed basis. Finally, add the object to your array to be exported.

Try this:

```
...
$x = New-Object System.Object
$x | Add-Member –type NoteProperty –Name UserName –Value $currentUser.SamAccountName
$i=0
foreach ($mailAdd in $currentUser.ProxyAddresses) {    
  $i++
  $x | Add-Member –type NoteProperty –Name "Emailaddress$i" –Value $mailAdd.SubString(5)      
}   
$usersOBJ += $x
```

Assuming you add all the users to $usersOBJ before exporting the csv, the columns should work perfectly for any number of proxy addresses.